# How do I use the pen tool for just one anchor point?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

It is quite hard to explain in words so I will show screenshots of what i would like.

This is a screenshot of what happens when I drag with the pen tool.

[image]

This is what I would like to happen.

[image]

Is there a shortcut to drag out only the first handle?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry this is well past any usefulness to the original poster most likely. I realize this is a very old question. However, this may be helpful to others. This has been a solution in Illustrator since practically it's inception and still works today (CC2018 the most recent version as of this writing).

---

Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key with the **Pen Tool** active and **click the anchor again**, after dragging.

This will set one side of the anchor to a corner while leaving the curve on the other side.

[image]

This **same method** will also function in **Photoshop** with it's **Pen Tool**.

---

Also note in either application, if you hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> and click-drag the open anchor, as opposed to merely clicking, you can create a *non-symmetrical* corner point.

Comment: Does this work for Photoshop also? (as indicated per question tag)

Answer (score 1):

You should use "conversion" trick of the pen tool -

When you make a point and leave the mouse - just click again on that point and it will be converted to what you want :

[image]

and after conversion -

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but is there any chance of a shortcut or something to do this .This is what I have been doing but I am trying to make a dress with many curves that will go like this and it would take far too long to do this on each curve, a shortcut to do it would be nice. @Ilan

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve actually. The way I described is the fastest and shortest to get 1-handled point. You can use mass conversion point tool for all selecting points, but the results will be unpredictable. The only shortcut for the tool is shift+c

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. The trick is start from the right point:

press down -> drag handle -> release mouse btn

and then just one click on the left point.

Here is what i get

[image]

Because when using **drag** to create a point, when this point is a **joint**, it will be a **smooth point** by default (2 side control handles). Only when it's a **starting point**, it will has only one handle.